# Do "National Councils" have national or international legal authority?

Tags: nationality

Really not sure if this is the correct stack exchange for this, but this seems like the right place. If there is a national council for for something, doesn't really matter what, but they are the only council for this in all the world, are their rulings technically correct all over the world?

I'm not sure if I explained this properly, please ask anything, and I will try to clarify if I was not clear enough.

Comment: Maybe an example would help....

Comment: So the actual thing will seem stupid, that's why I didn't post it, just a quarrel between friends. We were having an argument whether or not a hot dog was a sandwich, eventually I found that the National Hot Dog and Sausage Council stated that hot dogs are not a sandwich, his argument was that they are National and based in America, this is not where the hot dog originates from, therefore I'd be incorrect, however this is the only council for this, therefore, in my argument, because there are no other councils for this, their ruling is final, and that means hot dogs aren't sandwiches. Better?

Comment: Better, but I'd say other jurisdictions aren't bound by the American council's opinion...

Comment: @PatW. *Nobody* is bound by the American council's opinion.  They have no authority over the definition of "sandwich" in English or any other language. They have no authority over the hot dog, for that matter. They are just a trade association.  They can state an opinion like anyone else, and anyone is free to agree or disagree.  Jono: where did the hot dog originate, if not in America? It is derived from European sausages, but it is an American innovation.

Comment: @phoog True, but when courts have to decide strange stuff like this, industry practices via trade associations come up in opinions all the time

Comment: @PatW. I can't imagine that a hot dog's being or not being a sandwich would make a difference in any legal context.  But then again in a world where the Supreme Court can rule on whether a tomato is a fruit or a vegetable, I shouldn't put too much weight on what I can and can't imagine.

Comment: @PatW. FWIW most of the arguments offered in support of their position are facetious and/or logically fallacious.  I don't see anything that indicates they speak with any more authority than anyone else does on the subject.  In fact, they appeal to the authority of the USDA (also a questionable authority for matters of language, but undeniably authoritative in terms of legal definitions of food terms; these may not be identical to common definitions of food terms, however; for example if I make a sandwich containing 80% bread and 20% meat, it is not a sandwich according to the USDA).

Comment: @phoog We'd definitely avoid a citation to the Hot Dog Council, if feasible...:)

Answer (score 2):

No, each nation in the world is sovereign; that means the government of that nation decides what the law is for that nation.

If that government decides to create a "council" which has statutory powers then the laws they make are binding within their jurisdiction only.

If the council has no statutory power then it's just a group of guys getting together and saying stuff and it only applies to you if you decide it does.